# difference between Function Expression and Declaration

Tags: javascript, function

```js
var sing2 = () => {
  console.log("Function Expression")
}

function sing2() {
  console.log("Function Declaration")
}
sing2()
```

When I run the above function , I got output as **Function Expression** but when I ran the below code

```js
function sing2() {
  console.log("Function Expression")
}

function sing2() {
  console.log("Function Declaration")
}
sing2()
```

I got output as **Function Declaration** can someone help me understand reason behind this .

Comment: var hoisting is the reason for this

Comment: can you explain a bit more on this @mplungjan

Comment: See the dupe. basically the var will take precedence over the var that is defined by the function